# Getting Forbidden error while connecting to SP Online using CSOM Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, powershell-script

I have one powershell script where I am connecting to SP 2013 Library to download a file using Server side powershell script. After That in the same script file I am trying to connect to SP Online Library to upload the downloaded file using CSOM Powershell.

When I am trying to run the script It throws error when it trys to execute the "ExecuteQuery" of CSOM Method and getting below error"Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.""

If now I restart the machine and then try to execute the script it works fine. But some times the issue is irritating me.

Kindly help me in this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you restart your computer the csom script works, then it stops working after a period of time?

Comment: After 2-3 hours , sometimes after 5 hours it stops working.

Comment: Have you looked at the Idle session sign-out setting in the SP admin center?  URL:  https://YourCompany-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/accessControl

Comment: No, I haven't checked. But I can see yesterday the script was working fine for the whole day without issue. This issue suddenly comes and stays until I restart the system.